# Is there a way to have random positions for every key callback in modern OpenGL?

Tags: c++, glut, glm-math

I have used this C++ function to create random float numbers between 0.0 and 1.0.

```
float randomPositions()
{
    float randomNumber;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    randomNumber = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Then, by using the key callback function, I have declared positions with vectors of **randomPositions()** function

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    glm::vec3 positions[] =
    {
        glm::vec3(randomPositions(), randomPositions(), 0),
        glm::vec3(randomPositions(), randomPositions(), 0),
        glm::vec3(-randomPositions(), -randomPositions(), 0),
        glm::vec3(-randomPositions(), -randomPositions(), 0),
        glm::vec3(randomPositions(), -randomPositions(), 0),
        glm::vec3(-randomPositions(), randomPositions(), 0),
        glm::vec3(randomPositions(), -randomPositions(), 0),
        glm::vec3(randomPositions(), randomPositions(), 0),
        glm::vec3(-randomPositions(), -randomPositions(), 0),
        glm::vec3(-randomPositions(), randomPositions(), 0),
    };

    if (key == GLFW_KEY_E && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        pos++;
        trans = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), positions[pos]);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do that? Because as I can see, every run it has the same exact random position.

Comment: Do not use `srand`, especially not for floats, they will not be uniform. Just pick something from `<random>`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution contains an example at the bottom. In your case, you can make  `gen` global ( e.g. a `static` local variable).

Comment: @Quimby This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You are *initializing* the random number generator with `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));` on *every* `randomPositions()` call.

Given that the granularity of the `time()` function's return value is one second and given that the time it takes for your 20 `randomPositions()` is much less than 1 second, it is almost *guaranteed* that all your 20 values will be identical.

Move the call to `srand((unsigned)time(NULL));` outside of that function, preferably at some program initialization point.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `preferably at some program initialization point.`?

Comment: @NourJandali "Preferably": You should prefer, in an abstract sense, doing this to alternatives.  "At some": The following phrase describes a location we are talking about.  "Some": Not specific, generic.  "Program": A generic name for a piece of software.  "Initialization point": a spot or location where things are set up before the "real" work begins.  So you should do this at some point in your software where you set up the software before you do the real work, as opposed to doing it somewhere else.